# How is possible to exclude all automatic dependencies from being added in JBoss 7?

Tags: jboss7.x

I want to exclude all automatic dependencies in JBoss 7.
Was not able to find the answer here:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

*Added*

Automatic (implicit) dependencies are described here:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments

Now I need to do it explicitly. See below.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        </dependencies>

        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" />
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
            ...
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Question if I can do it using simple configuration like:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        </dependencies>

        <exclusions>
            <subsystem name="implicit" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic dependencies"?

Comment: The question is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. However, it wouldn't make sense anyway, as for example JDK is part of those implicit dependencies - you really don't want to deploy the entire JDK with your application, now, do you?

Create a set of implicit dependencies that you don't want and put them into jboss-deployment-structure like you have done.

Comment: I do not agree: Java Standard library is an "implicit dependency" of every Java application in every platform... Resteasy, Hibernate and so on... NO! It's a bad decision that forces developers to use red-hat tools

Comment: @thermz It's not a matter of opinion. Also, the JDK is splitted to separate packages and with JBoss only part of them is available by default even if JDK is included, as implicit or explicit dependency. This is to have control about the dependencies required by the application, which is the route java 8 takes also. I don't see how that forces people to use red-hat tools.

Comment: "it's not a matter of opinion" Well, apparently, Bill Burke (the Resteasy developer) doesn't think that way: http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/jboss-modules-suck-its-impossible-to-use-custom-resteasyjax-rs-under-jboss-7/#comment-6404 read his comment

Comment: @thermz I read the comment but I don't see how that's relevant to this discussion, maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: "How is possible to exclude all automatic dependencies from being added in JBoss 7" That's the point of discussion... your answer was "it wouldn't make sense anyway", his opinion is "JBoss Modules don’t suck. The implicit dependencies do.". You said ""it's not a matter of opinion" Well I think it's subjective instead, if you like Resteasy 3.06 to be added "under the hood" in your classpath that's ok for you. But for instance, what if you want to support many applications with different resteasy versions?

Comment: @thermz note that I was saying excluding *all* implicit dependencies doesn't make sense. Selectively excluding them, like Bill Burke in your link is doing, is completely ok and that's what I was suggesting as well. That way you can have support for many applications with different resteasy versions.